# The number of positive integers which divide 2004 to leave a remainder of 24

Tags: arithmetic

What is the number of positive integers that, when $2004$ is divided by them, leave a remainder of $24$?

A.  $036$

B.  $020$

C.  $022$

D.  $021$

E.  $014$

Comment: i tried using factorization method. i can find the numbers with remainder 0 like this..suppose i have 72.i can go in this way      1*72=72 (remainder=0); 2*36=72 (remainder=0)..and so on....but i cant find the sol. for the above question...:(

Comment: Look for the divisors of 2004-24.

Answer (score 7):

Let $a$ be the positive integer you're looking for. We know that 
$$ 2004 \equiv 24 \mod{a}$$
So we know, that there is an integer, let's say $k$ for which
$$ k \cdot a + 24 = 2004$$
Subtracting $24$ from both sides yields
$$ 1980 \equiv 0 \mod{a}$$
From
$$1980 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11$$
we can tell that $1980$ has 
$$3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2  = 36 $$ 
divisors, but we only need the ones that are greater than $24$, otherwise there couldn't remain $24$ when we divide $2004$ with $a$.

The divisors lesser than $25$ are: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18, 20$  and $22$;  $14$ divisors total. 
So the answer is $36-14 = 22$, that's option C.

(And here's the full list of solutions (I used brute force and ruby):
$30,
33,
36,
44,
45,
55,
60,
66,
90,
99,
110,
132,
165,
180,
198,
220,
330,
396,
495,
660,
990,
1980$.)

Comment: How can you say that it has 36 divisors? what about the 5 and 11?

Comment: Explained here: http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/Tau.html

Comment: @TylerHilton: this has $36$ divisors, since a number of the form $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ has $(\alpha_1 + 1) (\alpha_2 + 1) \dots (\alpha_k + 1)$ divisors.